# Generalized Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, parabolic-pde, brownian-motion

Consider the diffusion process
$$
d X = \mu(X, t) dt + \sigma(X, t) dY.
$$
When $Y$ is a Brownian motion, we know that the density follows the Fokker-Planck equation. Here I'm considering the general case where $Y$ is an independent and stationary process such as the Poisson process or a weighted sum of a Brownian motion and a Poisson process. How can we derive the associated Fokker-Planck equation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See, for example, [Generalized Fokker-Planck equation: Derivation and exact solutions](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.0274v2)

> We derive the generalized Fokker-Planck equation associated with the
> Langevin equation (in the Ito sense) for an overdamped particle in an
> external potential driven by multiplicative noise with an arbitrary
> distribution of the increments of the noise generating process. We
> explicitly consider this equation for various specific types of
> noises, including Poisson white noise and Lévy stable noise, and show
> that it reproduces all Fokker-Planck equations that are known for
> these noises.